# How to show page header and menu, when we click on the vertical tab using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

vertical tab using javascript. the vertical tab working fine, but i'm not able to see page header and menu part, when i click on the tab, only i can see div information.
header.

### HTML:

```
 <ul>
    <li><a href="#a1">a1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#b1">b1</a></li>          
    </ul>
    <div id="sections">
    <div class="section" id="a1">
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="bb">
    </div>
```

http://www.ommas.co.th/containerdesiccants.html, when we click on the tab, page not showing header and menu part. How to fix this

### Script 1:

```
     $(document).ready(function(){

    if (
        $('ul#verticalNav li a').length &&
        $('div.section').length
    ) {
        $('div.section').css( 'display', 'none' );
        //$('ul#verticalNav li a').each(function() {
        $('ul#verticalNav li a').click(function() { 
            showSection( $(this).attr('href') );
        });
  // if hash found then load the tab from Hash id
        if(window.location.hash) 
        {
   // to get the div id
           showSection( window.location.hash);
        }
        else // if no hash found then default first tab is opened
        {
            $('ul#verticalNav li:first-child a').click();
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

### Script 2

```
function showSection( sectionID ) {
    $('div.section').css( 'display', 'none' );
    $('div'+sectionID).css( 'display', 'block' );
}
$(document).ready(function(){

    if (
        $('ul#verticalNav li a').length &&
        $('div.section').length
    ) {
        $('div.section').css( 'display', 'none' );
        //$('ul#verticalNav li a').each(function() { // no need for each loop
        $('ul#verticalNav li a').click(function() { // Use $('ul#verticalNav li a').click
            showSection( $(this).attr('href') );
        });
        //});
        if(window.location.hash) // if hash found then load the tab from Hash id
        {
           showSection( window.location.hash);// to get the div id
        }
        else // if no hash found then default first tab is opened
        {
            $('ul#verticalNav li:first-child a').click();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**it's jumping to the `id`**

This is the default behavior for a `#hash` in an `href` of an `anchor`.

```
$('ul#verticalNav li a').click(function() { 
    showSection( $(this).attr('href') );
});
```

should be something like:

```
$('ul#verticalNav a').click(function(e) {
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href');//update hash manually
    showSection(window.location.hash);//with newly updated hash
    //no jumping :: added both to make more browser compatible
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

**the bigger picture**

this may be easier to maintain, and fixes other issues as well.

```
var vn = $('#verticalNav a'), ss = $('.section');//get elements

function showSection(sectionID) {
    $(sectionID).show().siblings().hide();//show current & hide siblings
}

if (vn.length && ss.length) {//if parts
    ss.hide();//hide sections
    vn.click(function(e) {//on tab click
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href');//update hash manually
        $(this).parent().addClass('on').siblings('.on').removeClass('on');//toggle active
        showSection(window.location.hash);//with newly updated hash
        e.preventDefault();//prevent default behavior
        return false;//return false
    });
    if (window.location.hash) {//if hash
        $('html, body').scrollTop(0);//no jump
        showSection(window.location.hash);//show slide
    } else {
        ss.eq(0).show();//show first slide
        vn.eq(0).parent().addClass('on');//make first tab active
    }
}
```

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/4sKNc/

Comment: Hi thanks, now working fine, but not show link below like this url with #id eg. http://www.ommas.co.th/containerdesiccants.html#strip-container-desiccant. thanks.

Comment: Hi thank you so much, now working fine, but when i click on the http://www.ommas.co.th/containerdesiccants.html but page directly going to call first id http://www.ommas.co.th/containerdesiccants.html#pole-container-desiccant what my mistake. thanks.

Comment: looks like `$('ul#verticalNav li:first-child a').click();` is triggering the click event and updating the hash on load. replace it with something like `$('.section').eq(0).show();` which should show the first slide, and it should work properly.

Comment: you may also want to add something like `$('html, body').scrollTop(0);` before `$('div.section').css( 'display', 'none' );` to prevent jumping on page load when a hash is present on load.

Comment: `ss=$('.section')`, but glad I could help!